# Tool for testing RESTful Web services

Tags: web-services, rest, soapui, rest-client, rest-assured

I am trying to evaluate the right tool to test RESTful  Web services and eventually automate the same for our project.
Wondering, what are the specifications I need to look for such test, when i compare various tools on internet.

Definitely, one of the requirements would be an Open source tool.

I have looked on few tools, such as SOAPUI,RestClient,TestMaker, RestAssured.  Wanted to know the pros and cons of them. Also, any ideas or pointers on how to go about it would be of great help.

Comment: If you just want to poke at APIs, try Postman Client for Chrome. Or our tools. For automated testing, you'll probably need to evaluate each one to determine if it fits your needs or not. There's no one-size-fits-all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need complex parametrized soap and rest webservices testing and test automation, you definetly should try soapui. It is open source (https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui), free in base edition tool with great documentation. In addition to webservices tests it provide scripting, load testing tool, ide support, web services mocking, running tests from GUI or console and much more.

Answer (score 19):

if you want to test from browsers,

use

> POSTMAN -> Chrome
>
> Rest Client -> Firefox

If you need an online tool or require automated API testing,

use

> [Runscope](https://www.runscope.com/)

Comment: +1 for Runscope. The Radar product is great.

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for aa HTTP client (GUI) to test requests, I'd mention:

- [Paw](https://luckymarmot.com/paw), a native HTTP client on Mac that supports most of the popular authentication schemes, has full encryption and obfuscation of your server credentials and dynamic values a special feature that lets you sent back a field from a previous request (e.g. an auth token) or compute the hash of another part of the request. Also generates cURL or client code. *(disclaimer: I'm the founder of Paw)*
- [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com), a Chrome app and a web wrapper for Mac that lets you send requests to servers. Generates cURL and client code. Cross-platform (web app). Has a cloud service for sharing of collections.
- [Insomnia](http://insomnia.rest/), a Chrome app but with a really nice interface (a design I like). It feels like the author cares about UI and design. The feature set isn't as complete as Paw or Postman though.
- [HDC Client](https://restlet.com/products/dhc/), Chrome app, quite old but Restlet acquired them and it seems like it's more active on the development. As test features like Postman.
- [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo), a Chrome app, similar to previous ones. Seems still quite popular but isn't very updated.
- [RESTed](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rested-simple-http-requests/id421879749?mt=12), a native Mac app, a very small feature set, just lets you test one request at a time. I mention this because I like the native feel (alike Paw) and I think it's a good alternative for those who just want something simple.

Also, you may consider this command line tool:

- [HTTPie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie): For a command line too, I personally love it. It's beautifully made, and easy to learn. Clearly not as handy as a GUI, but really worth a try.

I'd also recommend you to read through this list of tools I've made a few months ago: [Tools that will help you develop a RESTful API](https://restful.io/tools-that-will-help-you-develop-a-restful-api-cde98e628dd9)

Comment: Nice list of tools (some of them not so feature rich, but simple to use) and resources.
For additional list of such tools, you can check [12 Great Web Service Testing Tools](https://dzone.com/articles/12-great-web-service-testing-tools).